# Is there any command line tool in ubuntu to communicating with my chrome browser?

Tags: shell, google-chrome

I want to extract all the information from my chrome browser like currently open tabs, their html content and soon. Is there any method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Command to install to Google Chrome via shell:

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable -y
```

Command to connect to Google Chrome via shell:

```
google-chrome
google-chrome http://www.google.com
```

Comment: Does this anything else than just opening Chrome for that URL?